# Display HH:MM on y axis highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, highcharts

i need to create a highcharts chart with HH:MM on the y axis,
Is this doable? i have dates on the x axis and need to display HH:MM on stacked columns.
How can i do that?
Thanks!

Comment: from where are coming your datas...? give some code

Comment: Sebas, data is coming from a date field on a mysql table. i did not placed any code because i simply need to use HH:MM as data on the y axis columns instead of round or decimal numbers.

Comment: **@Gustavo** Hey, what is the status on this question?  Did the below answer help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the yaxis is of type datetime then the chart will render them the best way it sees fit. If you don't like the way they are rendered, you can control the datetime formats of the chart using [dateTimeLabelFormats](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--dateTimeLabelFormats). You can also control the interval of the dates shown using [tickInterval](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--tickInterval).  Based on the datetime span of the data at the time the chart will pick one of the following default formats:

```
second: '%H:%M:%S',
minute: '%H:%M',
hour: '%H:%M',
day: '%e. %b',
week: '%e. %b',
month: '%b \'%y',
year: '%Y'
```

If you want to force them all to the Hour and Minute no matter what the range is then set them as follows:

```
second: '%H:%M',
minute: '%H:%M',
hour: '%H:%M',
day: '%H:%M',
week: '%H:%M',
month: '%H:%M',
year: '%H:%M'
```

**EDIT**

To display the x-axis values on the columns: enable and format the [**dataLabels**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-column-dataLabels) on the column under plotOptions like below:

```
plotOptions: 
{
    column: 
    {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: 
        {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() 
            {
                  return ''+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M', this.x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```